# how to skip from a recored in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, nonetype

i make a loop to count number of word occurrence in list of word. so i use follow piece of code:

```
for i in range(len(traindocs_clean)):
    for word in traindocs_clean[i][1][0]:
        if traindocs_clean[i][1] is None:
            continue
        wordDict[word]+=1
```

but i know that there are some rows with null/NoneType/Blank value so when i run the code i will get follow error

```
     for word in traindocs_clean[i][1][0]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

i tried to  use keyword 'continue' and 'pass'to ignore these records and jump to next one but apparently it is not working.
i searched past comments and posts but i couldn't get proper answer so if you think that already there is some post same as this please share the link otherwise i appreciate if you help me with a solution.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for word in traindocs_clean[i][1][0]:
    if traindocs_clean[i][1] is None:
        continue
```

By the time the `if` condition checks if `traindocs_clean[i][1] is None` the `for` loop already tried to access (and iterate over) `raindocs_clean[i][1][0]`. If `raindocs_clean[i][1]` is `None` then it will fail before the `if` condition had a chance to verify that `traindocs_clean[i][1]` is not None.

To fix this you should move the `if` condition above the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(traindocs_clean)):
    if traindocs_clean[i][1] is None:
        continue
    for word in traindocs_clean[i][1][0]:
        wordDict[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the exceptions with a `try-except` block:

```
for i in range(len(traindocs_clean)):
    try:
        for word in traindocs_clean[i][1][0]:
            wordDict[word] += 1
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Note: It's better to not use pass and log or handle the error in a proper way.

Using `try-except` has another advantages as giving your the ability of handling multiple exceptions and/or doing running different commands in different situations. For example if your code is also prone to `IndexError` you can do:

```
    try:
        for word in traindocs_clean[i][1][0]:
            wordDict[word] += 1
    except (TypeError, IndexError):
        pass
```

Or if you want to treat with `IndexError` in another way:

```
    try:
        for word in traindocs_clean[i][1][0]:
            wordDict[word] += 1
    except TypeError:
        pass
    except IndexError:
        # do something
```